# What are the key differences between KeystoneJS and Strapi as tools to create CMS-driven apps?

Tags: web-applications, content-management-system, frontend, keystonejs, strapi

I'm leaning towards the idea that I'd use Keystone (as-is) for a standard, server-driven multi-page app and strapi when i want to stick Vue/React/Angular on the front-end for a SPA? Since it has a template/view already baked in, Keystone might be faster to get to MVP? Anything else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've been enjoying working with KeystoneJS v5 for over a year on multiple projects.
I had the same question as you and I picked Keystone over Strapi (even when git stars and  community were higher) because I was looking for a simple file based Backend Generator.

This line express it: `schema => ({AdminUI, GraphQLApi})`.

I needed to quickly define (and later easily modify) the Information Arquitecture of my backend, and seen it reflected automatically in a CMS and the API.

`(Strapi users, correct me if I'm wrong)` I saw that Strapi had more focus on building a Drag and Drop (no code) way of building this backend. I couldn't find a straight forward way of using Strapi with files and get the CMS and API I was looking for. Seemed to me that was built for people that wanted a backend, but didn't wanted to write code.

I rather use my code editor functions (find/replace, multicursor) to define and modify my schema than a Drag and Drop components on the browser. Also use previous projects as my based code to build new ones.

My keystone projects get a really simple file structure where most comes out of the box and making custom mutations, AdminUI components, hooks, and data seeding was really simple.

Here is an example:

```
├── index.js  // imports entities, hooks, initial-data, submodules
├── initial-data.js // imports seed/index.js and orchestastes how to create data 
├── entities // for each entity (list): field types, access control, hooks, adminUI configs
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── Users.js 
│   ├── Books.js
│   ├── Loans.js
│   ├── Authors.js
│   ├── ...
│   └── Categories.js
├── extendGraphqlSchema // pretty easy to add new custom Graphql types, mutations and queries  
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── types
│   ├── queries
│   └── mutations
├── hooks 
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── user_beforeUpdate.js
│   ├── book_validateInput.js
│   ├── ...
│   └── loan_afterDelete.js
├── keystone-media-server // submodule I use on many Keystone projects
│   ├── adapters
│   ├── fields
│   ├── lists
│   ├── resolvers
│   └── seed
└── seed // list of functions to create a complete data example to test
    ├── index.js
    ├── createUsers.js
    ├── createBooks.js
    ├── createLoans.js
    ├── createAuthors.js
    └── createCategories.js
```

Comment: Our structure is a tad more complex yes, we are working on better seed options though (same for data migrations) 

I'm a solutions engineer for Strapi.

Answer (score 6):

Not to familiar with KeystoneJS but from the look of it they are very similar. Strapi looks like it has a more extensible API but overall its the same concept. I have used Strapi for several projects and it's fast to work with, you can have Strapi up on Heroku with a fully built schema in less than an hour.

One thing between the two is GraphQL support, Strapi is making a significant push to get involved in GraphQL world, I believe in-order to keep up with Tipe.io.

Setting up GQL + Strapi + Nuxt / Next is wonderful for creating a SSR application.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I think Keystone is more wedded to REST, which I'm more familiar with, but I think I get how GraphQL is beneficial with client-based apps. I'm walking through a Strapi x GQL x Nuxt tutorial now. And thanks for the tip re tipe.io.

Comment: (Strapi is by default set to work with REST but offers a GQL plugin via `strapi install graphql` so you're GQL-ready in seconds)

Comment: Absolutely it does and it's nice because you don't really need to build out resolvers, the thing to keep in mind is if you plan on using GQL with other instances, there is a bit up a setup learning curve, especially if you are using subscriptions.

Answer (score 4):

At the time of this writing (nearly a couple years after this question was posted), Keystone 5 is oriented around graphql, so that is no longer a prime differentiator between the two. Keystone 4 is still being maintained as a REST-first framework.

Strapi is GQL-first now and has a larger community.

Comment: "Strapi is GQL-first now and has a larger community."

Hello, actually we are REST first and GraphQL is an optional plugin but we are working to make them equal in terms of features and support (REST is still quite a bit higher and our Admin panel will only speak to the backend via REST)